# Suggest best design patterns to update or insert bulk data

Tags: java, hibernate, design-patterns

I want to update or insert 100,000 records into a database in a single batch process using some effective design pattern.

Example: I have 1 million records in my table date range from 1/1/2020 to 1/1/2024 and if user updates any transaction in the middle, e.g. 1/1/2022, then based on that particular date I need to update the remaining records that come after 1/1/2022.

I am using Java and Hibernate.