# Design patterns - How Design patterns work with bulk data

Tags: java, hibernate, design-patterns

I want to update or insert 100,0000 records into a database in a single batch process using some effective design pattern.

Example: I have 1 million records in my table date range from 1/1/2020 to 1/1/2024 and if user updates any transaction in the middle, e.g. 1/1/2022, then based on that particular date I need to update the remaining records that come after 1/1/2022.

I am using Java and Hibernate.

Need to understand more about how design patterns work with bulk data and which design pattern I should learn for the above scenario?

Comment: Hello guys, I want some suggestion to learn design patterns which can work with bulk data update

Comment: How is this different to your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78246950/suggest-best-design-patterns-to-update-or-insert-bulk-data